# How to toggle backbone.js's model attributes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my js code I noticed many statements like:

```
model.set({someAttribute : !model.get("someAttribute")});
```

So I thought it may be useful to define custom method in the model:

```
toggle: function(attr, silent){
    this.set({attr: !this.get(attr)}, silent? {silent:true} : {});
}
```

The problem is, javascript javascript treats 'attr' as an actual key name instead of formal function parameter, so the code above doesn't work. Any suggestions how to solve this problem?
I want an elegant one-line solution.

Comment: It should say "javascript treats 'attr' as an actual KEY name"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there isn't an elegant one-line solution for this. in order to use `attr` as the key, you have to declare the object literal and then set it using the `[]` syntax:

```
toggle: function(attr, silent){
  var data = {}, value = this.get(attr);
  data[attr] = !value;
  this.set(data, {silent: silent});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you **had (edit)** all sorts of syntax errors with the "silent" portion of your function and I'm not sure what it is for, so I will focus on your question at hand.  This is the most elegant solution you are going to find, I think... "elegant" is subjective, of course.

Anyways, there is no way to have variable key names in the parameter initialization, so you need to use the index operator on a temporary object.

Here is how I solved it:

```
toggle: function(attr, silent) {
    var setter = {};
    setter[attr] = !this.get(attr);
    this.set(setter, silent? {silent: true} : {});
}
```

Comment: > Well, you have all sorts of syntax errors with the "silent" portion of your function.
What errors? Why?

I know this solution, I'm looking for something more elegant I can write in single line and single expression.

Comment: Well "all sorts of" is probably too intense.  But you do have mismatched curly braces.  As for my solution, you never said "I want an elegant one-line solution".  That is not how SO works.  You asked how to solve a problem and I gave you a solution.  What you want doesn't exist, as far as I know.  You can't have variable keys in your JSON syntax in Javascript.

Comment: > But you do have mismatched curly braces.
Where any why?
Ok, I added "I want an elegant one-line solution" statement to my question. I don't want to argue about the way "how SO works". I want help to my problem and I will mark it as solved only when I'll be satisfied with the answer.

Comment: @mnowotka: You've got to be kidding me.  You've got 4 left braces and 3 right braces.  Look here: http://www.screencast.com/t/0XFTOfp4

Comment: Oh, right, true! I already corrected this. But it has nothing to do with "silent" posrion.

Comment: @mnowotka: My point was that you posted code that did not parse.  It was ambiguous to where the silent was to go... was it to go in the first has, or the second?  Was there supposed to be a second hash? Or were they nested hashes? I figured it out and updated my response, but invalid code is invalid code.  period.

Answer (score 0):

```
toggle: function( attr, s ){
    this.set(
        function( aname, aval ){
            var o = {};
            o[aname] = !aval;
            return o;
        }( attr, this[attr] ),
        s? {silent:true}:{}
    )
}
```

Comment: One slight problem.  `this[attr]` should be `this.get(attr)` since backbone models use `set` and `get`